# Is ASP.NET (webforms) Incompatible with Google Website Optimizer Multivariate Testing?

Tags: asp.net, web, optimization, multivariate-testing

I've been stuggling all morning trying to get a multivariate test going in google website optimizer.

I've copy and pasted the header/footer code into the pages, and setup a basic page section just to see that everything is working.

When I try to validate the code its failing saying

```
"No sections detected on test page
TestSectionName - Unexpected or missing characters - Line: 422 Expected: </noscript>"
```

The silly thing is that the output is clearly there (I have used an asp literal to get around the asymetric noscript tag) and can clearly see it in the source as follows:

```
<script>utmx_section("TestSectionName")</script><h1>Buy This Product!</h1></noscript>
```

I've already tried disabling/removing the existing google analytics code in the site on the off chance that was conflicting with it with no luck.

I think there might be some incompatibility with the asp.net framework and this WSO framework. I was able to use exactly the same code saved into a raw html file with no asp.net/page content and have it validate ok.

e.g.

```
<html><head></head><body>
<!-- Google Website Optimizer Control Script -->
<script>
function utmx_section(){}function utmx(){}
(function(){var k='xxxxx',d=document,l=d.location,c=d.cookie;function f(n){
if(c){var i=c.indexOf(n+'=');if(i>-1){var j=c.indexOf(';',i);return c.substring(i+n.
length+1,j<0?c.length:j)}}}var x=f('__utmx'),xx=f('__utmxx'),h=l.hash;
d.write('<sc'+'ript src="'+
'http'+(l.protocol=='https:'?'s://ssl':'://www')+'.google-analytics.com'
+'/siteopt.js?v=1&utmxkey='+k+'&utmx='+(x?x:'')+'&utmxx='+(xx?xx:'')+'&utmxtime='
+new Date().valueOf()+(h?'&utmxhash='+escape(h.substr(1)):'')+
'" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></sc'+'ript>')})();
</script>
<!-- End of Google Website Optimizer Control Script -->

<script>utmx_section("TestSectionName")</script><h1>Buy This Product!</h1></noscript>


<!-- Google Website Optimizer Tracking Script -->
<script type="text/javascript">
if(typeof(_gat)!='object')document.write('<sc'+'ript src="http'+
(document.location.protocol=='https:'?'s://ssl':'://www')+
'.google-analytics.com/ga.js"></sc'+'ript>')</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
try {
var gwoTracker=_gat._getTracker("UA-xxxxx-1");
gwoTracker._trackPageview("/xxxxx/test");
}catch(err){}</script>
<!-- End of Google Website Optimizer Tracking Script -->

</body>
</html>
```

After all of this I am wondering if there is
a) anyone out there using asp.net with multivariate testing successfully
b) a known incompatibility with something in asp.net
c) known "donts" when it comes to coding with WSO multivariate testing
d) something really obvious I am missing?

Comment: sorry - my mistake, I didn't see that was noscript.

Answer (score 0):

I have used Google Website Optimizer multivariate tests on an ASP.NET website without any problem.

Have you tried putting `</noscript>` on its own line? I think I always put it on a blank line after the default section.